# Theorem: Anti-differentiation is harder than differentiation

Tags: logic, differential-algebra

The question of why anti-differentiation is "harder" than differentiation was the topic of [an earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20578/why-is-integration-so-much-harder-than-differentiation), and some of the answers are interesting, but I'm not sure they fully answer it, and this question will not be exactly the same.  Someone pointed out that in **numerical** work, integration is easy and differentiation is hard, and someone else spoke of local versus global.

There ought to be an answer **in the context of differential algebra rather than analysis**, so the local-versus-global issue and the numerical issues won't be there to complicate the question.

**Can the statement that one is easier than the other be made into a precisely stateable and provable theorem?  If so, how?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are talking here about *function terms*. The set of such terms (the "elementary functions") can be defined in a recursive way: $1$ and $x$ are  function terms, and if $A$, $B$ are terms then $A+B$, $\lambda A$, $A*B$, $e^A$ and a certain number of similar expressions are again function terms. Denote by ${\cal E}$ the set of terms established in this way. It is *easy* to prove that formal differentiation $D={d\over dx}$ is a map $D:\ {\cal E}\to{\cal E}$. Now the question arises whether this map is also surjective. We all know that it is not, but only a few of us have seen a proof of this, the reason being that this is an impossibility proof; cf. the proof that it is impossible to trisect an angle with ruler and compass. We have to show that there are instances $F$ of the "integration problem" that all finite length constructions of the theory at hand (substitution, partial integration, etc.) cannot solve. For such a proof we need a theory that *transcends* our bag of tricks, e.g. some sort of "differential Galois theory".