# Any derivatives that are difficult to take?

Tags: derivatives

Many integrals are either very complicated or in some cases impossible? However, I have not yet seen derivatives that are very difficult or cannot be solved for. Does anyone have an example of a derivative that cannot be solved through standard techniques?

Edit: I mean in one variable.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I meant in one variable.

Comment: The reason that derivatives are usually easy is the chain rule.  You'd have to find a function which can't be represented as the product/ composition of elementary functions.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem also logarithmic and implicit derivatives usually make things very easy too.

Comment: How about the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function)?

Comment: Interesting, as a hint, what definition of the cantor function should I use, because the Wikipedia "base 3 to base 2" looks sketchy and hard to use.

Comment: That probably is the best definition to figure it out.  Basically you have to recognize that the Cantor function is constant *a lot*.  So the derivative will be zero at each of the places where it's not undefined.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20578/why-is-integration-so-much-harder-than-differentiation and http://mathoverflow.net/a/16702/3092

Comment: Perhaps this is one of those things that are hard to reverse, like multiplication and factoring. Thanks for the links.