# Why can't certain integrals be found?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am a high school student and am a beginner in integral calculus. In one of my reference textbooks is said that there were certain integrals which “can't be found”.
Some of these include 
${\int}{\sin x\over x}\ {\rm dx}$, ${\int}{\cos x\over x}\ {\rm dx}$, ${\int}{1\over \log x}\ {\rm dx}$, ${\int}x\tan x \ {\rm dx}$

I graphed these equations in Desmos and found nothing strange. None of the explanations online made any senese and I failed to understand the following-

1)What about these functions makes them non-integrable?

2)Are there infinitely many functions like this?

3)Why does this happen when the curve is continuous and the area is well defined?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20578/87023 and https://mathoverflow.net/q/66377/37405

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those integrals *can* be found. You can compute them with any precision that want. The problem is that you cannot express them using only [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). This is a very broad class of functions which include probably any differentiable function that you've ever heard of.

Comment: But why only these functions? What limitation of these functions makes it impossible to express using elementary functions?

Comment: *These* functions *are* elementary functions. It's their *integrals* that cannot be expressed using only elementary functions. And actually the integrals of *most* elementary functions have that problem.

Comment: I know that these functions are elementary. But what about them makes their integral non-elementary? Why dont we face the same problem while integrating something like $sinx$ or $cosx$?

Comment: I suggest that you read about [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)).

Comment: @Sam: A related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral