# On the differential equation $y'(x)+\alpha y(ax)+\beta y(x)=f(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a method (or book) that treats differential equations of the following form:
$$y'(x)+\alpha y(ax)+\beta y(x)=f(x),\alpha, a\in\mathbb{R}^*, \beta\in\mathbb{R}.$$
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange! First, differential equations are [really hard](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782499/is-there-a-reason-it-is-so-rare-we-can-solve-differential-equations) to solve generally.  Second, there might often not be any $y(x)$ that satisfies differential equations of the form you describe (so maybe no method has been developed).  With this in mind, it's probably best if you give a specific example you're interested in for $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $f(x)$.

Comment: My example is $y'(x)=4y(x/2)-y(x)+a$ with $a\in\mathbb{R}.$.

Comment: Letting $y(x)=x^{2}$ has no effect on the right-hand side but adds $2x$ to the left.  Whereas, $y(x)=x$ adds $x$ to the right-hand side and $1$ to the left. Using these building blocks, I get the solution:
$$y(x) = \frac{a}{2}x^{2} + ax$$
Perhaps this approach can be generalized. It would be nice if someone knew the name of this kind of differential equation (if there is one).

Comment: Basically, we can add polynomials to the left-hand side of your equation:
$$y'(x)+\alpha y(ax)+\beta y(x)=f(x),\alpha, a\in\mathbb{R}^*, \beta\in\mathbb{R}.$$
The polynomials being factors of: $1 + (\alpha a + \beta)x$, $2x + (\alpha a^{2} + \beta)x^{2}$, etc.  Equating coefficients with $f(x)$, we can try and derive a taylor series for $y(x)$.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, $y(x)=\frac{a}{2}x^2+ax$ is a solution. Are there other solutions? And, how did you manage to choose $y(x)=x^2$ directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}p_{n}x^{n}$ and $f(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} q_{n}x^{n}$.

Then, the differential equation becomes:

$$\begin{align}
y'(x)+\alpha y(ax)+\beta y(x) &= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)p_{n+1}x^{n} + \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(a^{n} \alpha + \beta) p_{n}x^{n} \\
&= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[(a^{n} \alpha + \beta) p_{n} + (n+1)p_{n+1} \right]x^{n} \\
&= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} q_{n}x^{n}
\end{align}$$

This gives a relationship between the Taylor coefficients of $y(x)$ and $f(x)$ which we can equate to solve for the coefficients of $y(x)$.

If $p_{0} = y(0)$ is given, then we can uniquely solve for all the coefficients of $y(x)$ via the recursion:

$$p_{n+1} = \frac{q_{n} - (a^{n} \alpha + \beta) p_{n}}{n+1}$$