Why are some differential equations unsolvable?
I'm writing something about the double pendulum. I want to answer why the differential equation, which describes the movement of the double pendulum is analytically unsolvable.
Is there a general theorem that describes which differential equations are solvable/unsolvable? Or are we just too dumb to find an analytical solution? Or is there a proof for some special cases?
Thanks for the answers.
Remarks on where I can look the answers up for myselfe are also very helpful.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@LeoHorber: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782499/is-there-a-reason-it-is-so-rare-we-can-solve-differential-equations

Pretty much everything is unsolvable analytically really. Classroom examples of solvable systems are the exception rather than the rule.
