# Is derivative a one way function?

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, complex-analysis, cryptography

In lectures we have just defined integrals, and said that if we take a derivative of some set of functions, it is much harder to go back to the original set of functions, if we only know the set of derivatives. However, I recently started reading about one way functions(Wikipedia, nothing serious for now) and I wonder, if thus the derivative is a one way function ?

Comment: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function), the existence of such one-way functions is still an open conjecture.

Comment: @DietrichBurde So that means, that we can only see from computation time if it is "hard" to invert, right ?

Comment: They are more like functions that have multiple valued inverses than like one-way functions

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20578/why-is-integration-so-much-harder-than-differentiation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say *not really*, because of the **Risch algorithm.** It can, at least in principle, compute the anti-derivative of any elementary function if that function has an elementary anti-derivative. The complete description of the algorithm takes more than 100 pages though, so it is definitely much harder than systematically computing the derivative. Maybe Wikipedia is a good starting point if you want to learn more on the subject: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm

Comment: So basically we can say that the derivative is a "trap door" one way function and the private key is the Risch algorithm ?

Comment: @Bill I suppose so: But it is not a perfect analogy since there is no "hidden information." In principle, anybody could implement the Risch algorithm, while with RSA the private key can be truly hidden. Also, in my answer I am sweeping the following question under the rug: *How fast is the Risch algorithm?* Maybe there are functions which are easy to differentiate, but for which Risch takes a long time. I don't know much about this, however .