# What is the integral of $1/f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I've heard somewhere that the integral of $1/f(x)$ is not possible to answer in terms of $f(x)$, $f'(x)$, $F(x)$, and elementary functions. Is there an answer is terms of non-elementary functions? Why is $(1/f(x))'$ so simple in contrast to the integral?

Comment: Some answers to your last question: [Why is integration so much harder than differentiation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20578/why-is-integration-so-much-harder-than-differentiation)

Comment: It depends on what $f(x)$ is.